# MikroORM: How to query a date property by the day or month and not the full date?

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I have a entity with a date property

```
@Entity()
export class Foo {
    // ...other properties

    @Property({ type: DateType })
    date = new Date()
}
```

And I want to make a query to find all `Foo` that are from some specific day.

e.g.

```
async getByDate(someDate: Date) {
    const foo = await this.repository.find({
        // What should go to get Foo from the same day as `someDate` ?
    })
}
```

I couldn't find in the documentation how to do it.

I would also like to do things like "find `Foo` from some week" or "find `Foo` from from some month"

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to extract a day, week, or month from the Date object?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know how to pass to the MikroORM repository `find` method a query condition that will compare the `day` or `month` of a `date` property with the `day` or `month` of a `Date` variable. In plain javascript, I would do `foo.date.getDay() === someDate.getDay()`,  but I need MikroORM to do that in the database

Comment: Try something like this: `myDateRepository.getItems().forEach(d => d.getDay() == 1);`  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Comment: If you want it to run on the database side, I strongly suspect you need *filters* to do that.

Comment: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/query-builder/#using-sub-queries

Comment: Explains how to craft `where` conditions.  Just create a where condition using `getDay()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that v6 changed the `DateType` to map to a string instead.

If you use the `DateType`, you are mapping it to the `Date` object, so you should query by `Date` objects. The time part of the `Date` object will be truncated - that happens in the `DateType` so feel free to check its source code, it's quite straightforward.

```
const users = await em.find(User, { date: new Date('2020-05-20') });
```

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/packages/core/src/types/DateType.ts

From the implementation you can also see that in fact it does support querying by strings too, so this will work as well:

```
const users = await em.find(User, { date: '2021-04-20' });
```

To filter for a whole week, you need to first find the start and end of the week (will keep that for you), and use combination of `$gte` and `$lt` operators:

```
const users = await em.find(User, {
  date: {
    $gte: new Date('2021-04-19'), 
    $lt: new Date('2021-04-25'),
  },
});


// or with strings

const users = await em.find(User, {
  date: {
    $gte: '2021-04-19',
    $lt: '2021-04-25',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a month function, but I could just calculate the month by myself, which is something I haven't thought about it. And thanks for the awesome orm!

Comment: Actually you could also use SQL functions via custom SQL fragments. See https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/#using-custom-sql-fragments